# mysql join two tables

Tags: mysql, join

`table a`

```
id title
1   aaa 
2   ccc
```

`table b`

```
id title categories
1   123     24
2   222     5
3   333     6
```

How to join `table a` and `table b` like this:

```
id title categories
1    aaa    
2   ccc
1   123   24
2    222   5
3   333   6
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id, title, null as categories from a 
union all
select id, title, categories from b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` as:

```
SELECT id,title,'' AS categories FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT id,title,categories FROM b
```

Since `UNION ALL` expects the two result sets to have same number of fields I've added field named `categories` in the first query whose values is always empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to combine the data from the two tables such as:

```
Select id, title, "" as categories from tableA
UNION ALL
Select id, title, categories from tableB
```

In the first select query, empty string is provided as categories for column matching. UNION requires identical columns in both select queries. Also UNION ALL lists out the duplicates as well.